# How to map permissions to roles

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam, google-logging, gcp-stackdriver

`Permission denied. Please get bigquery.jobs.listExecutionMetadata or bigquery.jobs.listAll permission at organisation level to access Admin Resource Charts.`

I am getting the above error while trying to access the Monitoring dashboard in BigQuery.

Question: How do I find which role has these permissions so that role can be assigned to principle ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [roles at the organization level](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions_and_predefined_roles). Applying it to the organization level means that you provide permission to access all of a project’s BigQuery resources. These roles are used on the organization level because BigQuery Monitoring requires it.

The predefined roles that BigQuery has with these permissions are:

- bigquery.jobs.listExecutionMetadata
- bigquery.jobs.listAll
- BigQuery Admin
- BigQuery Resource Admin
- BigQuery Resource Editor
- BigQuery Resource Viewer

On the other hand, if you have these roles and BigQuery Monitoring is sending you the same error you probably have the roles set at a project level, applying it to a project level means that it will have only access to that project.

These are the required [permissions to use BigQuery Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/admin-resource-charts#permissions). See this to know how to [grant permissions at organization level](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org#grant-access).

Additionally, you can see all the BigQuery Roles in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery).